# while restoring mysql database, views changed into tables

Tags: mysql, view, restore

I have a full database dump and i restored it. But in my new restored server all the views are appeared as MyISAM tables. In early times dumps were restored perfectly. can anyone help me to trigger out the issue, please?

Regards,
Praveen

Comment: Which tool have you used to take a backup? can you paste a sample SQL which shows view's statement?

Comment: Please run this query : `SELECT IFNULL(engine,'View') engine,COUNT(1) table_count from information_schema.tables group by IFNULL(engine,'View');` show that output in the question.

Comment: I used below command for backup:  mysqldump --user=root --password=pwd --lock-all-tables --log-error=/var/lib/mysqlback/log/backup.log --all-databases > /var/lib/mysqlback/alldatabases.sql  and this for restore: mysql --user=root --password=pwd < /var/lib/mysqlback/alldatabases.sql

Comment: I have run the above query and result set is as below:  engine table_count
InnoDB 48
MEMORY 12
MyISAM 124

Comment: Which version of MySQL?  VIEWs have not always been around.  A dumb SELECT * would dump a VIEW as if it were a table.  Also, mysqldump has separate args for views, triggers, etc.

Comment: My MySQL version is 5.0.27-community-nt. Won't "mysqldump --all-databases" dump views and triggers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the backup script the views are first created as tables which are then dropped at the end of the script as each view is being created, so it seems that an error occurs while creating the views at the end of the script.

However when a view is created there is a user who is used in the DEFINER clause of the view who may not exist in your database, e.g., DEFINER=`user123`@`192.168.1.%`

I usually remove that clause in the backup script and it tends to work.

To verify add the -v option when importing the database

Comment: During long imports that seems like an error. Good catch!

Answer (score -2):

I replaced hostname 'localhost' with'%' and it worked...
I was trying to restore database using command prompt. while dropping table it was showing error 1227 which is related to user privileges. since the data was dumped from my local machine user credentials were also dumped in the file.